# python webbrowsing automation using proxy

Tags: python, web, proxy, automation

I'm coding some automation tool for a specific web site, and having some problems. The web site needs to access (such as pushing buttons) within a browser to get JSON format responses.

(I'm familiar with Python but not regarding network traffic such things. and sorry for my poor explanation, English is not my first language)

1. i have to listen to JSON format response from the web site, AFAIK, local proxy(127.0.0.1) is needed to fetch the traffic. I've found a code(http://luugiathuy.com/2011/03/simple-web-proxy-python/) that fetches data from port 80 (HTTP). however, the code needs to change network setting of my PC. is there any way not to change whole pc's proxy setting to get traffic data? it slows my pc. i want to run this code "independently?". i've tried to emulate independent web browser to handle this but i had hard time to figure out setting independent local proxy.
2. followed by question #1, the website needs some button action triggered by mouse. as i mentioned above(independently operatable), it has not to interfere actual mouse. is there any library i can use for this purpose? i've tried to create some "virtual mouse" to achieve this goal but sadly failed.

i have more detail questions but shorten down to most crucial ones.

Comment: Post what you have got so far.

Comment: @rosh i couldn't proceed my code, i have to solve this indepent-ability in first place. thank you for your fast attention.

Comment: You can use Selenium to automate browser operations.

Comment: @rosh i've just tried out proxy code i mentioned, and runned some codes using pyautogui.

Comment: @JohnGordon the webdriver supports proxy? i didn't think of that. thanks.